# Is there any problem with Android Market today?

Tags: android, uri, google-play

I have an application on the Android market and I have provided a link for the users to rate my app which will direct them to my market application page directly using [market-publishing](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketintent) link provided.

This was working perfectly well for some time now. Suddenly, today I'm not able to access the market page like that. I'm sure I haven't changed the code, and it does conform to the link given above.

Need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using something like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.android.example"));
startActivity(intent);
```

or opening a browser to a URL `http://market.android.com/blahblahblahwhatever`

I just tested the first case, and it works. Perhaps something has changed with your Market app's defaults? Try going into Settings > Applications > Manage Applications > (find your market, it is a system app most likely) > Clear defaults / Clear Data (depends on market version)

Comment: I was passing the context wrongly. I have it up and running now. Thanks for the answer anyways!